How do you list all userinstalled packages that have triggered the installation of a particular package?
Using dnf, I can see I have a particular package already installed on my machine : clevis.
$ sudo dnf list clevis
Installed Packages
clevis.x86_64                      20-2.fc40                                   @updates

I have not installed this package myself :
# Gives nothing:
sudo dnf history userinstalled | grep clevis

Using a one line command, I want to list all the userinstalled packages (packages returned by the command sudo dnf history userinstalled) that have directly or indirectly installed clevis.
I've tried several things:
# Only the direct parents of clevis are listed:
sudo dnf repoquery --alldeps --whatrequires clevis

# Gives nothing:
sudo dnf repoquery --userinstalled --whatrequires clevis

clevis may be a dependent package of several user installed packages. So I want the list of userinstalled packages that triggered the installation of clevis.
Thanks.
Update :
If I run :
$ sudo dnf repoquery --userinstalled --recursive --whatrequires clevis --qf "%{name}"
guestfs-tools
virt-win-reg

Which is great because those 2 packages are in the list returned by sudo dnf history userinstalled. But I've never asked to install virt-win-reg explicitly !
If I do sudo dnf history virt-win-reg it gives me:
$ sudo dnf history virt-win-reg
ID     | Command line                                                                                                                            | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   315 | install qemu virt-manager git wget libguestfs-tools p7zip p7zip-plugins make dmg2img tesseract tesseract-langpack-eng genisoimage vim n | 2024-06-01 13:28 | Install        |   48   

I can see exactly what was the command line of this line 315 in history by :
$ sudo dnf history info 315 | grep "Command Line" -A 1
Command Line   : install qemu virt-manager git wget libguestfs-tools p7zip p7zip-plugins make dmg2img tesseract tesseract-langpack-eng genisoimage vim net-tools screen

Nowhere I have explicitly asked for the installation of virt-win-reg and yet, dnf tells me it is a userinstalled package!
If I do the following command, I clearly see that virt-win-reg has been installed as a dependency :
$ sudo dnf history info 315 | grep -A 100 "Packages Altered"
... lots of lines...
    Install virt-win-reg-1.52.0-5.fc40.noarch                  @updates

When I run
$ sudo dnf repoquery --userinstalled --recursive --whatrequires virt-win-reg --qf "%{name}"

it returns nothing!
I don't understand how this works, how come 'virt-win-reg' has been installed as it is not a required package by any other package, and how can virt-win-reg considered a 'userinstalled' package...
Update 2:
so it appears that it is guestfs-tools that provides the virt-win-reg package :
$ sudo rpm --query --info virt-win-reg                       
Name        : virt-win-reg
Version     : 1.52.0
Release     : 5.fc40
Architecture: noarch
Install Date: Sat Jun  1 13:28:34 2024
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 49010
License     : GPL-2.0-or-later
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Sat Apr 13 01:00:02 2024, Key ID 0727707ea15b79cc
Source RPM  : guestfs-tools-1.52.0-5.fc40.src.rpm
Build Date  : Fri Apr 12 23:31:19 2024
Build Host  : buildvm-x86-22.iad2.fedoraproject.org
Packager    : Fedora Project
Vendor      : Fedora Project
URL         : http://libguestfs.org/
Bug URL     : https://bugz.fedoraproject.org/guestfs-tools
Summary     : Access and modify the Windows Registry of a Windows VM
Description :
Virt-win-reg lets you look at and modify the Windows Registry of
Windows virtual machines.

I didn't know that an RPM could provide many packages...
That's all very well, but that does not answer my question : which package I explicitly asked for installation, has indirectly installed 'clevis'...
Update 3:
$ sudo dnf repoquery --whatrequires clevis                                                                                                                                      
clevis-luks-0:20-1.fc40.x86_64                                                                 
clevis-luks-0:20-2.fc40.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                
clevis-pin-tpm2-0:0.5.3-5.fc40.x86_64
fdo-client-0:0.5.0-1.fc40.x86_64

I've checked: clevis-luks and clevis-pin-tpm2 are installed on the system.
$ rpm -qa | egrep 'clevis|fdo-client'
clevis-pin-tpm2-0.5.3-5.fc40.x86_64
clevis-20-2.fc40.x86_64
clevis-luks-20-2.fc40.x86_64


Are there any dependents of clevis installed on the system? If there aren't and there is just clevis, then that is why those commands don't have any output. That clevis may be a dependency of one or more user-installed packages is neither here nor there. It needs to actually be a dependency of one or more of those packages in order for those commands to actually return anything.

@NasirRiley: sudo dnf autoremove does not remove clevis.

That isn't relevant to what I stated.

@NasirRiley : "Are there any dependents of clevis installed on the system?" sudo dnf repoquery --whatrequires clevis clevis-luks-0:20-1.fc40.x86_64 clevis-luks-0:20-2.fc40.x86_64 clevis-pin-tpm2-0:0.5.3-5.fc40.x86_64 fdo-client-0:0.5.0-1.fc40.x86_64
none of them are packages I've installed using dnf install.

Regardless of whether you installed them, are any of them on the system? What is the output of rpm -qa | egrep 'clovis|fdo-client? Add that and other information to the question. Do not post it in the comments where it is more difficult to read and can get lost.

Ok, thx, See Update 3 in the question.

Then clevis and its dependents weren't explicitly installed by a user which is why your yum repoquery --userinstalled commands have no output. You said this yourself and the information that I asked for confirms this. That's what --userinstalled means. That's all you need.

You'd need to do that recursively:
s=( clevis )


get all the userinstalled packages depending on any element of s, dnf repoquery --userinstalled --whatrequires ${s[@]}.
if that is nonempty, you're done and found user-installed packages depending on your package.; else go to 1.2.
if the above is empty, add all direct dependencies s+=( $(dnf repoquery --alldeps --whatrequires ${s[@]}) ) and go back to 1.


I have tried what you said, it doesn't work, I have no output :
[jrx@fedora ~]$ echo $s
clevis
[jrx@fedora ~]$ sudo dnf repoquery --userinstalled --whatrequires ${s[@]}
[jrx@fedora ~]$ s+=( $(sudo dnf repoquery --alldeps --whatrequires ${s[@]}) )
Last metadata expiration check: 0:44:38 ago on Sat Jul 27 16:50:39 2024.
[jrx@fedora ~]$ sudo dnf repoquery --userinstalled --whatrequires ${s[@]}
[jrx@fedora ~]$ ```
